# Flutter/Flutter.h file not found in Xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode, header-files, build-error

I am trying to build my Flutter iOS app in Xcode, but I am getting the following error:

```
'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqwgaclmizdztbgwvyuydjgnmjad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_3AO5QSACASUGH-clang_24K6MS22YMY0N.pch' for bridging header '/Users/user/development/projects/flutter/project/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
in file included from /Users/user/development/projects/flutter/project/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:
```

I have tried the following steps to resolve the error:

- I have removed the `ios` folder and created a new one.
- I have run `pod install` in the `ios` folder.

I am still getting the error. What else can I do to resolve this error?

**Additional information:**

- Flutter version: 3.13.7
- Xcode version: 15.0
- No error displayed in the output of `flutter doctor -v` command:

  ```
  [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64, locale
      en-MY)
      • Flutter version 3.13.7 on channel stable at
        /Users/user/development/flutter
      • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
      • Framework revision 2f708eb839 (10 days ago), 2023-10-09 09:58:08 -0500
      • Engine revision a794cf2681
      • Dart version 3.1.3
      • DevTools version 2.25.0

  [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
      • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
      • Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.2
      • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
        Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
      • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
        17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
      • All Android licenses accepted.

  [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
      • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
      • Build 15A240d
      • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

  [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
      • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

  [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
      • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
      • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
         https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
      • Dart plugin can be installed from:
         https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
      • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
        17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

  [✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
      • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
      • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

  [✓] Connected device (2 available)
      • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64
      • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.70

  [✓] Network resources
      • All expected network resources are available.

  • No issues found!
  ```